# Problem with grid refreshing after closing radwindow

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radwindow

I have problem with radgrid refreshing, when i close the popuup radwindow,can any one help to figure out the problem.

my Gridpage aspx code looks like this

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" OnAjaxRequest="RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest" EnableAJAX="true">
            <AjaxSettings>
                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxManager1">
                    <UpdatedControls>
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" />
                    </UpdatedControls>
                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid1">
                    <UpdatedControls>
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" />
                    </UpdatedControls>
                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            </AjaxSettings>
        </telerik:RadAjaxManager>

<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
            GridLines="None" ShowGroupPanel="True" Skin="Black" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" AllowAutomaticInserts="false" AllowAutomaticUpdates="false">
            <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="True" AllowColumnsReorder="True" ReorderColumnsOnClient="True">
                <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" />
                <ClientEvents OnGridCreated="OnGridCreated" />
            </ClientSettings>

.......................
..................
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" EnableShadow="true"
            Skin="Black">
            <Windows>
                <telerik:RadWindow ID="UserListDialog" runat="server" Height="620px" Width="620px"
                    Left="150px" Top="50px" ReloadOnShow="true" ShowContentDuringLoad="false" Modal="true"
                    OnClientClose="closeRadWindow" />
            </Windows>
        </telerik:RadWindowManager>

protected void RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Argument == "Rebind")
            {
                RadGrid1.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.Clear();
                RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GroupByExpressions.Clear();
                Presenter List = new Presenter(this);
                IList<FileAdmin> GridDta = List.PopulateGrid();
                RadGrid1.DataSource = GridDta;
                RadGrid1.Rebind();
            }
My javascript looks like this
function closeRadWindow()
                 {
                     $find("<%= RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("Rebind");

                }
       function refreshGrid()
                 {
                   $find("<%= RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("Rebind");

                 }
```

RadWindow aspx code Looks like this
javascript

```
function CloseAndRebind() {
                        GetRadWindow().BrowserWindow.refreshGrid();
                        //GetRadWindow().close();
                    }
function GetRadWindow()
                     {
                        var oWindow = null;
                        if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow; //Will work in Moz in all cases, including clasic dialog
                        else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow; //IE (and Moz as well)
                        return oWindow;
                    }
```

Radwindow aspx.cs file looks like this

```
protected void buttonclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (result == true)
 {
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "mykey1", "CloseAndRebind();", true);
 }
}
```

Comment: For clarification purposes, are you wanting the grid to update with the changes (so you can see the new data) following the closing of the radwindow?

Comment: Yes , that particular functionality is not working

Comment: Honestly, it looks as though you have mirrored the example [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandwindow/defaultcs.aspx?product=window) to the tee. Is the result == true passing in your code, allowing the following code to execute?

Comment: I had same problem. I followed link example but updating by calling ajaxRequest, Rebind() didn't happen. Instead, Calling rebind from Javascript solved problem

Answer (score 2):

Modify the JavaScript closeRadWindow method like mention bellow

```
function closeRadWindow(oWnd, eventArgs){

     var grid= $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
     grid.rebind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a very similar method to what tHARA_sOFT used...

```
    function refreshGrid(arg) {
      var grid = $find("<%= grdResults.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
      if (!arg) { //If we have arguments, then we need to jump to the page we were on
        grid.CurrentPageIndex = grid.PageCount - 1
      }
      grid.rebind();
    }
```

That gives me the Rebind, and RebindAndNavigate, rolled into one.  All Javascript based...